# Getting ul height of bootstrap dropdown with max-height set always results in max-height

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing conditional logic that will detect where my bootstrap dropdown is in relation to the window and conditionally add the class `dropup` so that the dropdown will expand upwards.

I have a three dropdowns inside of some table columns, and all three dropdowns have a different amount of items in them. Here's an example of one.

```
<td class="form-group" ng-controller="DropupController as up">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown keyboard-nav 
          ng-class="{ 'dropup': up.isDropUp }" ng-click="up.toggleDropUp($event)">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" dropdown-toggle>
            {{ otherController.text }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="simple-btn-keyboard-nav">
            <li ng-repeat="item in otherController.collection" role="menuitem" 
                 ng-class="{ 'selected-dropdown-item' : item.ID == otherController.collection.ID }">
             <a href="#" ng-click="otherController.setItem(item.ID)">
             {{ item.text }}</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input hidden id="itemValue"
           name="itemValue" ng-model="otherController.ID" required /> 
          <!-- for validating the form -->
</td>
```

I have an AngularJS DropupController with a function that is triggered when a dropdown is clicked.

```
app.controller('DropupController', function () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.isDropUp = false;
    vm.toggleDropUp = ToggleDropUp;

    function ToggleDropUp($event) {
        var dropdownContainer = $event.currentTarget;
        var position = dropdownContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var buttonHeight = dropdownContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height;

        var dropdownMenu = $(dropdownContainer.nodeName).find('.dropdown-menu');
        var menuHeight = dropdownMenu.outerHeight();

        var $win = $(window);

        alert('MenuHeight: ' + menuHeight); //Debugging

        if (position > menuHeight && $win.height() - position < buttonHeight + menuHeight) {
            vm.isDropUp = true;
        }
        else {
            vm.isDropUp = false;
        }
    }
});
```

And I have some css so that I can set the `max-height` of the actual `ul` menu element and handle some other oddities with my new behavior.

```
.selected-dropdown-item {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropup .caret {
    border-top: 4px solid;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The left-most dropdown has a lot of items, enough to hit to `max-height` and trigger the scrollbars. The middle dropdown has only 5 items in it and the right-most dropdown has 8 items in it. These last two do not hit the `max-height`.

This logic works great for the dropdown that can fill up the whole 300px `max-height` of the `ul` element. However, it seems that the other two dropdowns will end up with the `menuHeight` variable in the controller being set to 300 pixels as well, causing the menu to dropup when it doesn't need to. If I comment out the dropdown that's hitting the 300 pixel `max-height`, then the height being reported for all of the remaining dropdowns is the left-most existing dropdown (which has 5 items in it). Repeating this to remove the middle dropdown results in the last remaining dropdown reporting the height of it's contents correctly.

So in essence, getting the height for the dropdowns will always pull the height for the left-most dropdown, regardless of which dropdown I toggle. I suspect it's a scope issue relating to `$event.currentTarget` and jQuery's `.find`, but I can't be sure and I'm not sure how to further diagnose it or solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you replace var dropdownMenu = $(dropdownContainer.nodeName).find('.dropdown-menu'); with $(dropdownContainer).find('.dropdown-menu');  nodeName in your case would be div.

Comment: @CristiTodoran: Good call removing nodeName. Totally missed that. I had added it during troubleshooting and it never left. Feel free to create an answer for the interweb points.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace var dropdownMenu = $(dropdownContainer.nodeName).find('.dropdown-menu'); with $(dropdownContainer).find('.dropdown-menu'); nodeName in your case would be div.